# How do you set the default package and/or diagram in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: configuration, enterprise-architect

This is small item, but how do you configure what a project looks like when it is opened (e.g. which diagram is shown)?

I have a project that always opens to a diagram from an older package in the EA project.  And since it isn't the first model in THAT package, I figure that it must be configurable.

In summary, when I open my project, I want to see the 1st diagram of "Package B" instead of having the 2nd diagram of "Package A" (which is what its been doing since I've been using the project file).

I am on version `13.0.1307`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the diagram
In the ribbon, click Layout
then in the Diagram Section, click Manage
Then you have the option to set the Diagram as the Model default (It will be the default for everyone)
or as the User Default(It will be the default only for you)
[image]

You can also right-click en empty space in the diagram and select "Set as User Default Diagram"
[image]

If you want to go back to the User/Model default diagram at any time, you can use the active windows arrow
[image]
Also (unrelated, but still useful) You can use [Working sets](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/user_interface/working_sets.html)

Comment: You just made my week!

Comment: Using Enterprise Architect v15 RC - In the Layout Ribbon the "Manage" icon is now called "Options", and "Set as Model Default" is there.

Comment: They changed it again in Enterprise Architect 15.1. To find this action go to "Start" Ribbon, then in the icon "Workspaces" select the "Manage" menu under the "Model Places" group, then "Set Current as Default".

Comment: And then the question is: how to remove this default diagram? Also using 13.0 like the original poster.