# How to remove the default model diagram in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: settings, enterprise-architect

In [How do you set the default package and/or diagram in Enterprise Architect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43053661/9418831) it's very clearly shown how to set the default diagram for a model, so that all the users would get it opened on load of the project. But how can one disable this setting once it is done, so that no diagrams are opened on load of the project?

Answer (score 2):

Typical EA:

- Create a dummy diagram
- Assign that as model default
- Delete the dummy

(They might have introduced a fix, but all the years that's what I did. Has been asked 10 years ago: [Sparx Forum](http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,19302.msg179428.html#msg179428) and even [my own post](http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,17595.msg171914.html#msg171914))

Answer (score 2):

In case If any one still looking for a direct way to remove the default diagram from a model in version **15.1**
Choose option **Start | Desktop | Workspaces | Model Places | Manage | Clear**

[image]